# How do I create a guild in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I was just wondering how you create a guild in Guild Wars 2?

Beta weekend starts tomorrow and I am going to need to create our guild, but I have not seen anything about how to create one in GW2.

**What are the requirements?**

**Where do I go?**

**Do I need currency?**

**Do I need people to sign a charter?**

Any other details would be great.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need a charter or to go to a special area, though you *can* create a guild by speaking to a Guild Registrar in a city.

You will need to have **1 silver** in order to create a guild. Then all you need to do is open the Guild window (<kbd>G</kbd> by default), choose a name (31 character limit) and guild tag (an abbreviation that will show up next to your character name, up to 4 characters), and that's it.

Note that guild members don't even have to have be on the same Home World (server) as you, though you *do* need to be on the same Home World if you wish to play World vs. World together.

The default maximize size for a guild is 50 members. In order to increase this size, you will need to speak to a Guild Registrar. The following table from the [official wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guild#Costs_to_increase_guild_size) lists the costs and upgrades as follows:

```
Tier   Membership Cap    Cost
 1          50         1 Silver 
 2          100        1 Silver
 3          200       10 Silver
 4          300        1 Gold
 5          400        1 Gold
 6          500        2 Gold
```

Comment: @FAE As of BWE3 (and I guess at launch?) it now costs 1 silver to create a guild?

Comment: As @Gwen stated, it now costs to create a guild. http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guild#Creation

Comment: Well, I tried making a Guild several times and it was a pile of fail. Tried creating a guild both at a Guild Registrar (in Lion's Arch and Smokestead) and by just clicking "G". Couldn't form a Guild if my life depended on it. And yes, I did try different guild names and tags and every time I clicked "create" nothing would happen.

Comment: Did you have the required 1 silver?

Comment: Creating the guild is a bit buggy at the moment, for the pre-launch early access weekend folk. Lots of players are reporting the inability to create a guild, and some who do manage to create one are plagued with the inability to talk or invite people to the guild. Best bet is to just let them sort out the issues.

Comment: @RWUlf-X Same thing was happening to my bf and I. Try creating your guild once you're outside of towns or cities. That's what ended up working for us.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, there was a specific NPC Guild Registrar (He was near the Auction House in Divinty's Reach, not sure about the location in the other cities) that would allow you to create a guild as well. It may be that you need to go talk to him in later versions, but for now, he simply forced you into the same interface as above.

Comment: I believe that npc is there just for looks and fluff. Because there was an npc for promoting guild members and other stuff too.

Comment: The Guild Promoter wasn't for promoting members, he was there for buying Guild Influence with Gold. It had a linear curve, but he could "Buy drinks for the town" and just change money into influence. Was a neat system, but didn't have enough coordinated friends or time to see if any of it worked.

Comment: Neat, we didn't really have time to experiment with all of that. We were too busy enjoying the game. lol.